# How to override target URI for a web service reference in VS 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, wcf, web-services

This seems like it should be really simple, but I'm unable to figure this out.

I am adding a web service reference to my console application. The web service points against our production environment and I would like to test it against development. In VS2005 it was really easy to override the target URI of the service. Is it possible to do the same with VS2008? I would like to set the URI in code or via a config file.

I would really appreciate help with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in your .config, you should see `<endpoint>` elements that were added to the `<client>` section of `<system.serviceModel>`. Assuming you need to point at only one environment at a time you can simply edit the `address` attribute of those endpoints to point to whatever URL you want.

If you wanted to change this at runtime you need to use the constructor overload for the client proxy that was created. There should be several overloads that take a parameter called `remoteAddress` in many forms.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I was able to get around this issue by going to "Add Service Reference" -> "Advanced" -> "Add Web Reference". This gives me a reference in the form I am most familiar with. Now I was able to override the constructor with the URI parameter. Is that method frowned upon?